# Prolog find family eldest and youngest children in list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

i am new to Prolog. Due to i taking paradigm programming subject, i need to learn different programming in every few weeks.

i got an exercise in find eldest and youngest children in families, below is my knowledge database.

```
family( person(alex, fox, date(26, oct, 1970), work(ucl, wc1e)),
      person(lan, fox, date(6, dec, 1971), unemployed),
      [ person(adrian, fox, date(17, nov, 1996), unemployed),
        person(lisa, fox, date(7, june, 2002), unemployed)
      ]).
family( person(james, bond, date(29, feb, 1950), work(mi6, secretLocation)),
      person(girl, bond, date(01, dec, 2004), unemployed),
      []).
family( person(superman, hero, date(29, feb, 1979), unemployed),
      person(superwoman, hero, date(29, feb, 1979), work(crisisSpot, anywhere)),
      [ person(superbaby, hero, date(7, june, 2002), unemployed) ]).
family( person(picard, captain, date(29, feb, 2400), unemployed),
      person(kirk, captain, date(29, feb, 2300), unemployed),
      [ person(janeway, captain, date(29, feb, 2450), unemployed),
        person(cisco, captain, date(29, feb, 2450), unemployed)
      ]).
```

I already solved the rest question just only this question i tried a couple times still got no idea, I'm having trouble understanding is how the children in list work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
% Find eldest children in family
dateofbirth(person(_,_,Date,_), Date).
eldest(X,Y) :-
   family(_,_,Kids),
   member(X,Kids),
   dateofbirth(X, date(_,_,Y)),
   (dateofbirth(X, date(_,_,Y)).
```

Above is my answer i trying, but still not working.

Comment: What means eldest? Is this just according to the year or also the day and month?

Comment: Year among children. Thank you for the reply. According year to find out who is eldest or youngest children in families.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the relation shall describe the eldest kid, I think a one-place predicate is called for, e.g. eldestkid/1. Then it would be helpful to have all the kids in a list. If you examine at the first 2 goals of your predicate eldest/2 ...

```
   ?- family(_,_,Kids),member(X,Kids).
Kids = [person(adrian,fox,date(17,nov,1996),unemployed),person(lisa,fox,date(7,june,2002),unemployed)],
X = person(adrian,fox,date(17,nov,1996),unemployed) ? ;
...
```

... they give you all the kids bound to the variable X one-by-one. So let's use setof/3 to get all those kids in a list:

```
   ?-  setof(X,A^B^Kids^(family(A,B,Kids),member(X,Kids)),L).
L = [person(adrian,fox,date(17,nov,1996),unemployed),person(cisco,captain,date(29,feb,2450),unemployed),person(janeway,captain,date(29,feb,2450),unemployed),person(lisa,fox,date(7,june,2002),unemployed),person(superbaby,hero,date(7,june,2002),unemployed)]
```

The rest is pretty straight forward:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

eldestkid(K) :-
   setof(X,A^B^Kids^(family(A,B,Kids),member(X,Kids)),L),
   eldest_in(K,L).                     % K is the eldest kid in L

eldest_in(EK,[K|Ks]) :-                % the first kid in the list
   eldest_in_(EK,Ks,K).                % is the eldest so far

eldest_in_(EK,[],EK).                  % empty list: ESF is eldest
eldest_in_(EK,[K|Ks],ESF) :-           % case 1: the Eldest So Far
   dateofbirth(K, date(_,_,KY)),
   dateofbirth(ESF, date(_,_,ESFY)),
   ESFY =< KY,                         % is elder that K ...
   eldest_in_(EK,Ks,ESF).              % hence still the ESF
eldest_in_(EK,[K|Ks],ESF) :-           % case 2: the ESF
   dateofbirth(K, date(_,_,KY)),
   dateofbirth(ESF, date(_,_,ESFY)),
   ESFY > KY,                          % is younger than K
   eldest_in_(EK,Ks,K).                % hence K is now the eldest

dateofbirth(person(_,_,Date,_), Date).
```

Example query:

```
   ?- eldestkid(K).
K = person(adrian,fox,date(17,nov,1996),unemployed) ? ;
no
```

Note that eldest_in_/3 is only comparing years, as suggested in your comment. If you want to take into account the month and the day as well, you need to write a predicate for that and replace the comparison-goals in eldest_in_/3 accordingly.

Comment: Thank for your useful explanation and reply! Your code is work but i need some time to understand your code. Thank again for your helping.